# Is it possible to use Huawei developer API via Google Apps Script?

Tags: huawei-developers, appgallery-connect

1 According to [this](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agcapi-getstarted-0000001111845114) guide I created API Client;

2 I try to run this Apps Script to get access token and get error 502.

```
var url = "https://connect-api.cloud.huawei.com/api/oauth2/v1/token";

  var options =
  {
    "method" : "POST",
    "contentType" : "application/json",    
    "payload" : {
      "grant_type" : "client_credentials",
      "client_id" : "700000000000000000",
      "client_secret" : "4*********************A"
    }
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch( url, options);
  Logger.log(response);
```

Is anybody can test this small code? Have you propositions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed!

```
var url = "https://connect-api.cloud.huawei.com/api/oauth2/v1/token";  
  var options =
    {
      method : "POST",
      contentType : "application/json",
      payload:JSON.stringify({
        "grant_type":"client_credentials",
        "client_id":"000000000000000000",            
        "client_secret":"LONG_STRING"
      })      
    };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch( url, options);
  var access_token = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()).access_token;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use Huawei developer API via Google Apps Script?

As far as I know, Huawei doesn't have any restrictions, but it's not clear if Google does.

> I try to run this Apps Script to get access token and get error 502.

error 502 indicates that a network error between servers on the internet, meaning the problem wouldn't be with your computer or internet connection. Meanwhile you can try:

- Refreshing/reloading the page
- Closing all open tabs or windws and start a new session.
- Clearing your Browser’s Cache and Cookies.
- If none of above worked, try Another Browser or restart your PC.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not helped

Comment: Fixed now!!!!!!